# Typescript generics: how to ensure function args match each other?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to have a function with a arg of a certain type, and "matching" literal. How can I do that?

```js
class T1 {
  val: string = "abc"
}
class T2 {
  val: number = 123
}
type TType = 'T1' | 'T2'

// I want to make this generic so the args have to "match"
function foo(ttype: TType, arg: T1 | T2) {
  console.log(`${ttype}: arg.val`)
}

foo('T1', new T1)
foo('T2', new T2)
foo('T1', new T2) // I want this to be a compile-time error
```

I'd like the code to require that when 'T1' is passed as `ttype`, an object of type T1 is required as the second arg and vice versa. I don't want two versions of the function if I can avoid that (don't want to copy the body) -- just a type spec that says "either literal T1 and a T1, *or* literal T2 and a T2". I'm happy to set up the mappings manually -- I don't need to get the class name from the string literal. Just don't know how to approach this in Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simples approach is to use overloads

```
function foo(ttype: "T1", arg: T1): void
function foo(ttype: "T2", arg: T2): void
function foo(ttype: TType, arg: T1 | T2) {
  console.log(`${ttype}: arg.val`)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/PTAEDcEMBsEsBNIBdYHsB2A6JBnAUAMbSQ46gAqAjKAN56gQwBcoOSATrOgOagC8oAESQARgUF4AvoWKkKAJlr1G0FugCuAWxEBTdv1CV5AZil4kATwAOOiuWu2BAcipPQAH1Av5TvHhCgAJKgAO6Q6EigSKigmpAA1rZIABawZNw66HqwBKwxKbaQ7NxkyZDgSTGCcUgEyRIAZuroBCgYoA2oqAAUSJY2LIJUggA0oEXcLFQAlCzgqAh4TS1t6B1dvf06g+Tyo+PFU-KzEAvwS82taGudPX0OU-Y2YxNT1J6700oMBBg4qNAdJhoKhuN0AAYAEho9xskhYE0wUGg4OmZiWGxclCcYyyIQolDRt263hxoDxCiJmNcuJ0+M+QA)

You could also go with a generic function with a mapping interface, but for the example that would probably be overkill:

```
type TMap = {
  "T1": T1
  "T2": T2
}
// I want to make this generic so the args have to "match"
function foo<T extends TType>(ttype: T, arg: TMap[T]): void
function foo(ttype: TType, arg: T1 | T2) {
  console.log(`${ttype}: arg.val`)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEDcEMBsEsBNIBdYHsB2A6JBnAUAMbSQ46gAqAjKAN56gQwBcoOSATrOgOagC8oAESQARgUF4AvoWKkKAJlr1G0FugCuAWxEBTdv1CV5AZil4kATwAOOiuWu2BAcipPQAH1Av5TvOYcUALKQVgZ0DIJUgixUypHy0QpmIKAAkqAA7pDoSKBIqKCakADWtkgAFrBk3DroerAErAUVtpDs3GTlkOBlBYJFSATlEgBm6ugEKBigI6ioADzkoDoAHki18GTk9jYAfAAUSJY2MQA0oG3cMcFWANrkALoAlCzgqAh4YxNT6DNzh8cdDEdjpzpcYtRPOR5E8lAwCBgcKhoDpMNBUNx9gADAAkNCODkkLEumCg0CxTzMn3+LkoTnOdQyFEolNmqH23npoEZClZNNcDJ0TOhTyAA)

Comment: Perfect -- overload is exactly what I need. Didn't realize they worked like that. Thanks!